# How can I run through three separate arrays in the same for loop?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have three arrays I am trying to run through and I want to use the values from all three arrays in one function. This might sound confusing but here is what I have:

```
    var Name = [Joe, Sarah, Chad]
    var Age = [18, 20, 22]
    var Gender = [Male, Female, Male]

    for name in Name {
        for age in Age {
            for gender in Gender {   
                makeUser(name, userAge: age, userGender: gender)
            }
        }
    }
```

This runs but what I get is: (makeUser prints out the 3 values)

```
Joe, 18, Male
Joe, 20, Male
Joe, 22, Male

Joe, 18, Female
Joe, 20, Female
Joe, 22, Female ....
```

And so on.

All I want is

```
Joe, 18, Male
Sarah, 20, Female
Chad, 22, Male
```

Is this possible? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are always sure the arrays will be equal in length, then you are better to just loop through one of the arrays and use it's index to reference the others:

```
for (index, name) in enumerate(Name) {
    makeUser(name, userAge: Age[index], userGender: Gender[index])
}
```

However, I would recommend getting this data into a dictionary, but I assume this is just sample data to illustrate a point. :)

Comment: .enumerated now

Answer (score 30):

This is a very common requirement so the standard library caters to it with a function, `zip`:*

```
for (a,b) in zip(seq1, seq2) {
    // a and b will be matching pairs from the two sequences
}
```

Unfortunately, as of right now, `zip` only does pairs, even though in theory it could be overloaded to do triples.  However, it’s not a big deal, you can just nest them:

```
var names = ["Joe", "Sarah", "Chad"]
var ages = [18, 20, 22]
var genders: [Gender] = [.Male, .Female, .Male]

for (name,(age,gender)) in zip(names,zip(ages,genders)) {
    makeUser(name, userAge: age, userGender: gender)
}
```

Note, it will only serve up to the shortest sequence, so if there are more names than ages or genders, you’ll only get the matching names.

This might seem like a down side compared to using an index, and this might also seem more complex, but the alternative’s simplicity is deceptive.  Bear in mind what would happen if you used `indices` or `enumerate` alongside arrays that didn’t match – you’d get an array out of bounds assertion (or you’d have to put in checking logic).

`zip` avoids this problem.  It also means you can use sequences instead of collections, as well as working with collections that don’t have integer indices (unlike `enumerate`) or collections that have different index types (e.g. a `String` and an `Array`).

*(in the current beta, anyway – `zip` returns a `Zip2` object.  In Swift 1.1, you need to create the `Zip2` version directly as `zip` has only just been introduced)

Answer (score 5):

You could use a custom `zip3` function, which is not hard to write.

```
struct Zip3Sequence<E1, E2, E3>: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    private let _next: () -> (E1, E2, E3)?

    init<S1: Sequence, S2: Sequence, S3: Sequence>(_ s1: S1, _ s2: S2, _ s3: S3) where S1.Element == E1, S2.Element == E2, S3.Element == E3 {
        var it1 = s1.makeIterator()
        var it2 = s2.makeIterator()
        var it3 = s3.makeIterator()
        _next = {
            guard let e1 = it1.next(), let e2 = it2.next(), let e3 = it3.next() else { return nil }
            return (e1, e2, e3)
        }
    }

    mutating func next() -> (E1, E2, E3)? {
        return _next()
    }
}

func zip3<S1: Sequence, S2: Sequence, S3: Sequence>(_ s1: S1, _ s2: S2, _ s3: S3) -> Zip3Sequence<S1.Element, S2.Element, S3.Element> {
    return Zip3Sequence(s1, s2, s3)
}

let names = ["Joe", "Sarah", "Chad"]
let ages = [18, 20, 22]
let genders = ["Male", "Female", "Male"]

for (name, age, gender) in zip3(names, ages, genders) {
    print("Name: \(name), age: \(age), gender: \(gender)")
}
```

The above code prints:

```
Name: Joe, age: 18, gender: Male
Name: Sarah, age: 20, gender: Female
Name: Chad, age: 22, gender: Male
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `zip` with 3 arrays (test they are indeed the same length):

```
for (name, (age, gender)) in zip(names, zip(ages, genders)) {
    makeUser(name, userAge: age, userGender: gender)
}
```

But maybe the cleanest of them all is just old fashioned C-style:

```
for i in 0..<names.count {
    let name = names[i]
    let age = ages[i]
    let gender = genders[i]
    makeUser(name, userAge: age, userGender: gender)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See below. However, your code will crash if any of these arrays differs in size from the others.

```
var Name = ["a", "b", "c"]
var Age = [1, 2, 3]
var Gender = ["m", "f", "m"]

for (var i = 0; i<Name.count; i++) {
    var name = Name[i]
    var age = Age[i]
    var gender = Gender[i]
    makeUser(name, userAge: age, userGender: gender)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the enumerator as an array and use functional methods to map the result to what you want.

```
var Name = ["a", "b", "c"]
var Age = [1, 2, 3]
var Gender = ["m", "f", "m"]

let results = Array(Name.enumerated())
    .map {($0.element, Age[$0.index], Gender[$0.index])}
```

Comment: Pls add something with answer as above.