# Iterate over two arrays simultaneously

Tags: arrays, swift, iteration

I am new to Swift. I have been doing Java programming. I have a scenario to code for in Swift.

The following code is in Java. I need to code in Swift for the following scenario

```
// With String array - strArr1
String strArr1[] = {"Some1","Some2"}

String strArr2[] = {"Somethingelse1","Somethingelse2"}

for( int i=0;i< strArr1.length;i++){
    System.out.println(strArr1[i] + " - "+ strArr2[i]);
}
```

I have a couple of arrays in swift

```
var strArr1: [String] = ["Some1","Some2"]
var strArr2: [String] = ["Somethingelse1","Somethingelse2"]

for data in strArr1{
    println(data)
}

for data in strArr2{
    println(data)
}
// I need to loop over in single for loop based on index.
```

Could you please provide your help on the syntaxes for looping over based on index

Comment: Your java code is unsafe to begin with, as it assumes that strArr2 is the same length or longer than StrArr1 (which in the hard-coded arrays you have works, but in code where the arrays could change, would not work).

Comment: Yes, the java code is just an example. We have a check if strArr1.length == strArr2.length, else we return.

Answer (score 168):

You can use `zip()`, which creates
a sequence of pairs from the two given sequences:

```
let strArr1 = ["Some1", "Some2"]
let strArr2 = ["Somethingelse1", "Somethingelse2"]

for (e1, e2) in zip(strArr1, strArr2) {
    print("\(e1) - \(e2)")
}
```

The sequence enumerates only the "common elements" of the given sequences/arrays. If they have different length then the additional
elements of the longer array/sequence are simply ignored.

Comment: So zip() takes 2 arrays, and returns an array of tuples of common elements in both arrays? Is `zip()` swift 2 syntax, or is `zip2`? Your first sentence implies that `zip` is the swift 1.2 syntax, but the last bit makes it sound like `zip` is the Swift 2 syntax.

Comment: @DuncanC: You are right, the last edit was misleading. The `zip()` function works in both Swift 1.2 and Swift 2, only the underlying sequence type changed from `Zip2` to `Zip2Sequence`. – It takes two sequences (arrays are just a special case) and returns a (lazily evaluated) sequence with the tuples of the common elements.

Comment: Can we print all elements of two different size array ?

Comment: Why do they all have to have the same type? It seems like a pointless limitation
Edit: My problem wasn't related to type; gives me the same error anyway: Cannot invoke 'zip' with an argument list of type '([Float], [Float], [Float])'

Comment: @pete: The Swift `zip` function takes *exactly two* sequences as arguments, Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/48753610/1187415, or https://forums.swift.org/t/zip3-zip4/218 in the Swift forum.

Answer (score 37):

With Swift 5, you can use one of the 4 following Playground codes in order to solve your problem.

---

## #1. Using [`zip(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip) function

In the simplest case, you can use `zip(_:_:)` to create a new sequence of pairs (tuple) of the elements of your initial arrays.

```
let strArr1 = ["Some1", "Some2", "Some3"]
let strArr2 = ["Somethingelse1", "Somethingelse2"]

let sequence = zip(strArr1, strArr2)

for (el1, el2) in sequence {
    print("\(el1) - \(el2)")
}

/*
 prints:
 Some1 - Somethingelse1
 Some2 - Somethingelse2
 */
```

---

## #2. Using `Array`'s [`makeIterator()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688032-makeiterator) method and a while loop

It is also easy to loop over two arrays simultaneously with a simple while loop and iterators:

```
let strArr1 = ["Some1", "Some2", "Some3"]
let strArr2 = ["Somethingelse1", "Somethingelse2"]

var iter1 = strArr1.makeIterator()
var iter2 = strArr2.makeIterator()

while let el1 = iter1.next(), let el2 = iter2.next() {
    print("\(el1) - \(el2)")
}

/*
 prints:
 Some1 - Somethingelse1
 Some2 - Somethingelse2
 */
```

---

## #3. Using a custom type that conforms to [`IteratorProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/iteratorprotocol)

In some circumstances, you may want to create you own type that pairs the elements of your initials arrays. This is possible by making your type conform to `IteratorProtocol`. Note that by making your type also conform to `Sequence` protocol, you can use instances of it directly in a for loop:

```
struct TupleIterator: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {

    private var firstIterator: IndexingIterator<[String]>
    private var secondIterator: IndexingIterator<[String]>

    init(firstArray: [String], secondArray: [String]) {
        self.firstIterator = firstArray.makeIterator()
        self.secondIterator = secondArray.makeIterator()
    }

    mutating func next() -> (String, String)? {
        guard let el1 = firstIterator.next(), let el2 = secondIterator.next() else { return nil }
        return (el1, el2)
    }

}

let strArr1 = ["Some1", "Some2", "Some3"]
let strArr2 = ["Somethingelse1", "Somethingelse2"]

let tupleSequence = TupleIterator(firstArray: strArr1, secondArray: strArr2)

for (el1, el2) in tupleSequence {
    print("\(el1) - \(el2)")
}

/*
 prints:
 Some1 - Somethingelse1
 Some2 - Somethingelse2
 */
```

---

## #4. Using [`AnyIterator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anyiterator)

As an alternative to the previous example, you can use `AnyIterator`. The following code shows a possible implementation of it inside an `Array` extension method:

```
extension Array {

    func pairWithElements(of array: Array) -> AnyIterator<(Element, Element)> {
        var iter1 = self.makeIterator()
        var iter2 = array.makeIterator()

        return AnyIterator({
            guard let el1 = iter1.next(), let el2 = iter2.next() else { return nil }
            return (el1, el2)
        })
    }

}

let strArr1 = ["Some1", "Some2", "Some3"]
let strArr2 = ["Somethingelse1", "Somethingelse2"]

let iterator = strArr1.pairWithElements(of: strArr2)

for (el1, el2) in iterator {
    print("\(el1) - \(el2)")
}

/*
 prints:
 Some1 - Somethingelse1
 Some2 - Somethingelse2
 */
```

Comment: love zip! Never knew about that.... I always used counters to iterate through loops... me and my C coding skills haha!

Answer (score 21):

Try This:

```
zip([0,2,4,6], [1,3,5,7]).forEach {
    print($0,$1)
}

zip([0,2,4,6], [1,3,5,7]).forEach {
    print($0.0,$0.1)
}
```

Comment: great! This also works for arrays with different sizes

Comment: @KamenDobrev No, it doesn't

Answer (score 14):

You could also `enumerate` over one array and used the index to look inside the second array:

Swift 1.2:

```
for (index, element) in enumerate(strArr1) {
    println(element)
    println(strArr2[index])
}
```

Swift 2:

```
for (index, element) in strArr1.enumerate() {
    print(element)
    print(strArr2[index])
}
```

Swift 3:

```
for (index, element) in strArr1.enumerated() {
    print(element)
    print(strArr2[index])
}
```

Comment: This has changes to strArr1.enumerate() in the latest version of swift.

Comment: This code will crash if first array has more elements than second array. You should add `guard strArr2.indices.contains(index) else { break }` at the beginning of the for loop to make it safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i = 0; i < strArr1.count ; i++)
{
    println(strArr1[i] + strArr2[i])
}
```

That should do it. Never used swift before so make sure to test.

> Updated to recent Swift syntax

```
for i in 0..< strArr1.count {
    print(strArr1[i] + strArr2[i])
}
```

Comment: C-style for loops are deprecated in Swift 3.0.

Comment: Thanks @PopKernel, posted this before Swift 3.0 was out.

Comment: I wasn't criticizing, just adding that info for other people

Comment: Didn't think you were. @PopKernel

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Range` if you still want to use `for in`.

```
var strArr1: [String] = ["Some1","Some2"]
var strArr2: [String] = ["Somethingelse1","Somethingelse2"]

for i in Range(start: 0, end: strArr1.count) {
    println(strArr1[i] + " - " + strArr2[i])
}
```

Comment: Or shorter: for i in 0..<strArr1.count {...}

Answer (score 0):

```
> Incase of unequal count 

let array1 = ["some1","some2"]
let array2 = ["some1","some2","some3"]

var iterated = array1.makeIterator()
let finalArray = array2.map({ 
                 let itemValue = iterated.next()
                 return "\($0)\(itemValue != nil ? "-"+itemValue! : EmptyString)" })
```

// result : ["some1-some1","some2-some2","some3"]

Comment: Please Update your Ans. If you don't know the size of array then it will not work.