# How to zip arrays in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

```
let array1 = ["Albert","Bobby"]
let array2 = ["Charles", "David"]
```

How do merge two array so that the out put would be `["Albert", "Charles", "Bobby", "David"]`

Comment: Do you only want to zip arrays of the same type?  Do you ever want to zip more than one array?  Will the arrays ever have a different number of elements in each?

Comment: @EICaptain It's not a sort.  It's a zip.

Comment: you can get your output easily, if you take first elements from both array and add it to new array .. like wise in for loop

Comment: check this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217690/iterate-over-two-arrays

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `zip` to combine your two arrays, and thereafter apply a `.flatMap` to the tuple elements of the zip sequence:

```
let array1 = ["Albert","Bobby"]
let array2 = ["Charles", "David"]

let arrayMerged = zip(array1,array2).flatMap{ [$0.0, $0.1] }

print(arrayMerged) // ["Albert", "Charles", "Bobby", "David"]
```

Answer (score -3):

Give this a shot

```
   var a = ["one", "two"]
   var b = ["three", "four"]

   var c = a + b
   print(c)
```

Comment: This isn't what is being asked.  Reread the question.