# How do I control the flow on multiple for-in loops swift 2?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, mapbox

I have mulitple for- in loops but I'm not sure how to bounce back up to the top loop each time for the four geojson records I have that are individual arrays, place, pass and lat/long.

Code:

```
                for aPlace in place {
                    print(aPlace)
                    for aPass in pass {
                        print(aPass)
                        for var (i, x) in zip(lat, long) {
                            print(i)
                            print(x)

                //These must be in this order to load right at least from what I have seen thus far
                var point = MGLPointAnnotation()
                point.title = aPlace
                point.subtitle = aPass
                point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: i, longitude: x)
                print(point)
                print(" ")
                mapView.addAnnotation(point)
                //after this the code jumps to pass type record2
                    break
                }; break; continue
            }
        }
```

I have some error checking prints in the there to help me understand what is going on...

this is what I get printed out...

```
North Shore Trailhead
passRecord1
48.066736
-123.835361
<MGLPointAnnotation: 0x7fa9b3a37630; title = "North Shore Trailhead"; subtitle = "passRecord1"; coordinate = 48.066736, -123.835361>

Lyre RiverTrailhead
passRecord1
48.066736
-123.835361
<MGLPointAnnotation: 0x7fa9b1c2aa40; title = "Lyre RiverTrailhead"; subtitle = "passRecord1"; coordinate = 48.066736, -123.835361>
```

Having a different trailhead location in record 2 is what I want so that is ok. After that it just records the same passRecord# and same lat/lon which is then reported to the MGLAnnotation which is a mapbox marker.

Is there a better way to do this? I have searched for hours to find an explanation for this to no avail.

Documentation:

[AppleDoc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID121) has a part on label statements but I can't seem to get that to work either.

if you look at nested loops in this [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/for-swift) it will show what the program is doing...just don't know how to fix it...

Answer (score 1):

- you are iterating over all places
- for each place, you are iterating over all passes
- for each place-pass combination, you are iterating over all i-x combinations
- the first break is breaking out of the most inner loop, so only the first i-x pair is processed
- the second break is in the middle loop, so only one pass is processed
- the continue never gets reached because the second break jumps out here

proposal:

- comment out the break- and continue statements and observe what happens
- think about how this is different from what you expect
- either fix it or come back here and explain to us

Comment: Ok so when I do that I get this result...

North Shore Trailhead
passRecord1
48.066736
-123.835361
<MGLPointAnnotation: 0x7f878985fe10; title = "North Shore Trailhead"; subtitle = "passRecord1"; coordinate = 48.066736, -123.835361>
 
48.091941
-123.801919
<MGLPointAnnotation: 0x7f8789946f80; title = "North Shore Trailhead"; subtitle = "passRecord1"; coordinate = 48.091941, -123.801919>

I want trailhead1, passRecord1, lat/lon for point #1, and it printed in annotation form, then

trailhead2, passRecord2, lat/lon2, and annotation2 such and so forth through all the records

Comment: okay, easy version: iterate over all indexes (from 0 to smaller count elements) and then access the proper fields in each list.

Comment: hard version would be to iterate over all arrays at the same time by some fance map-filter-reduce call. you can for example look here if something fits your needs: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/

Comment: interesting, think you need to use zip() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217690/iterate-over-two-arrays

Comment: maybe you can zip all 4 arrays at once and get out the 4 variables?

Comment: if not, you could merge them with zip(zip(a,b),zip(c,d))

Comment: these are great suggestions, I think the stackoverflow question is where I learned about zip. I tried zipping all four arrays but not using that method. I'll give it a whirl, if no go, I'll look at map further, seems like a useful tool. I tried the index method but I may have missed something on that in my debugging phase of that portion..