# combining conditions in for loops swift

Tags: swift, loops

as my last Question was marked a a duplicate i am going to rephrase it and give an example:

i want to create a list with a variable amount of packages, where each package consists of a name, 2 coordinates and some other information.
I have an algorithm which sets an annotation on a map for each of those packages.

The problem i have is, that i need to write a new algorithm for each annotation. So i thought of using a for-loop which inserts the information inside of each package into the algorithm and repeats that for every single package. The problem here was so far that i would need more than one condition serving the for-loop which didnt work out for me. It is also quite difficult to adress the different parts of information inside of the packages specifically.

I hope it gets clearer now what i meant and someone has an idea how to solve the problem.

Comment: `zip` might be what you are looking for, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/29218063/1187415.

Comment: Getting less clear... Please provide a concrete example of inputs and expected output.

Comment: the only thing that could really help here would be code. Please provide an [mcve] then it might get clearer what the actual problem is

Comment: It's unanswerable as unclear and lacking an MCVE. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip` like suggested by Martin. You can then iterate over each element of the array at the same time.

```
let x = [0, 1, 2]
let y = [5, 4, 3]

for (_x, _y) in zip(x, y) {
    print("pair: \(_x) \(_y)")
}
```

Comment: There is no need to use stride here. `for i in 0..<x.count` or `for i in x.indices`

Comment: Those are two extra ways I can add to my answer then :-)

Comment: hmm not really what i was Looking for

Comment: @Gustulus lol You'll have to give us a bit more feedback then that if you're going to expect someone to be able to help you

Comment: i will try to explain my idea a little better

Comment: @AndyIbanez I recommend to remove all by the `zip` solution. There's absolutely no reason to be using the other 3 ways.

Comment: You may need to clarify your question then. Based on the description and attempt you write with that `for`, it looks like to me you want to iterate through both arrays at the same time.

Comment: so my idea is to have a specific number of packages which all consist or a title and 3-4 values (a mix of numbers and strings)

Comment: and now i have an algorithm which uses these packages each for themself (first it prints the name and then it uses the other values) and i want this algorithm to do this procedure on every single package so in the end i have a list of all the packages

Comment: let me give you an example:

Comment: you have a map and you want to set annotations and now you create a list of "packages" which all consist of the specific name of this Annotation, the coordinates and some other random information

Comment: and now i want my algorithm (which creates the annotations and sorts out the layout and stuff) to use these "annotation-packages"  and set annotations at the given coordinates with all the Information given in each"package"

Comment: i hope it gets a little bit clearer now