# Iterate through Multiple Arrays

Tags: swift

How do I iterate through multiple arrays in a for loop. I am aware of the zip method, but what if i have 9 arrays?

```
var usernames        = [String]()
var avatars          = [PFFile]()
var postDescriptions = [String]()
var locations        = [String]()
var latitudes        = [String]()
var longitudes       = [String]()
var postFiles        = [PFFile]()
var dates            = [Date]()
var uniqueIDs        = [String]()
```

and as you can see, they are of multiple formats.

Comment: o_O You should refactor the code to use a struct if you have 9 parallel arrays.

Comment: You should **not** have 9 arrays, you should have one `User` class and **one** array of instances of that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zip` itself it a sequence, so in principle you could write:

```
for (username, (avatar, (postDescription, (location, (latitude, (longitude, (postFile, (date, uniqueID)))))))) 
    in zip(usernames, zip(avatars, zip(postDescriptions, zip(locations, zip(latitudes, zip(longitudes, zip(postFiles, zip(dates, uniqueIDs)))))))) {
        // use `username`, `avatar` etc.
}
```

(See also [How can I run through three separate arrays in the same for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686647/how-can-i-run-through-three-separate-arrays-in-the-same-for-loop) for other options)

Alas, **look at this mess**!  You should really just define a structure that contains all 9 attributes:

```
struct User {
    var username: String
    var avatar: PFFile
    var postDescription: String
    var location: String
    var latitude: String
    var longitude: String
    var postFile: PFFile
    var date: Date
    var uniqueID: String
}
```

and then work on one array only:

```
var users = [User]()

for user in users {
    // use `user.username`, `user.avatar` etc.
}
```