# Swift: Exit nested for loop whilst maintaining outer loop's for index

Tags: swift, for-loop

I'm fairly new to Swift and I'm sure this is a relatively straight forward question. I have a nested for loop and I would like to break out of the inner loops after appending the data to an array. Below is my code:

```
            for set in self.setArray{
                self.itemData = "Set "
                self.itemData += set
                self.itemData += "  "
                for reps in self.repsArray{
                    self.itemData += reps
                    self.itemData += " Reps  "
                    for weight in self.weightArray{
                        self.itemData += "Weight "
                        self.itemData += weight
                        self.itemData += "kg"
                        structSetArray.append(self.itemData)
                        self.itemData = ""
                        break
                    }
                    break
                }
            }
```

Currently the break statements allow me to return back to the **set** array and retrieve the next item, however, this causes the **reps** and **weight** arrays to start from the beginning again. How can I prevent this from happening so all the loops retrieve the second item?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run through three separate arrays in the same for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686647/how-can-i-run-through-three-separate-arrays-in-the-same-for-loop)

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to imagine what your intention might be (and you have not explained it), so I'll give two hypotheses with two different answers. (Note that in doing so I'm going to eliminate your `self.itemData` and replace it with a local variable.

---

Perhaps you're trying to loop thru **three arrays at the same time**. To do that, use `zip` and just *one* `for` loop.

This would be easier if `zip3` existed natively; you could write it, but there's really no need:

```
let zippedArray = zip(setArray, zip(repsArray, weightArray))
for tuple in zippedArray {
    let set = tuple.0
    let reps = tuple.1.0
    let weight = tuple.1.1
    var itemData = "Set "
    itemData += set
    itemData += "  "
    itemData += reps
    itemData += " Reps  "
    itemData += "Weight "
    itemData += weight
    itemData += "kg"
    structSetArray.append(itemData)
}
```

In real life, however, it would be better to have just *one* array whose elements are a *struct* with three properties (`set`, `reps`, and `weight`).

---

On the other hand, it might be that you're trying to loop through **all possible *combinations*** of your three arrays. In that case, move all the "printing" of values into the innermost loop, like this:

```
        for set in self.setArray{
            for reps in self.repsArray{
                for weight in self.weightArray{
                    var itemData = "Set "
                    itemData += set
                    itemData += "  "
                    itemData += reps
                    itemData += " Reps  "
                    itemData += "Weight "
                    itemData += weight
                    itemData += "kg"
                    structSetArray.append(itemData)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should  probably add tuple naming for best practice? `tuple.0.1.1.2.3.1.2.1.1` gets really confusing really fast

Comment: @Vollan We shouldn't really be zipping at all; we should be looping through one array. The basic data model is faulty.

Comment: @matt Yes, i agree, but if the model can't be fixed, then zip and tuple is a good solution, but should be used in the best way possible, dont you agree?

Comment: @Vollan I'm not going to change what I wrote (I'm not even sure I've guess the OP's intentions correctly). If you want to submit your own answer, go ahead!